# Weird behavior on .bash_profile on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, ubuntu

## Problem Descript

### Scenario

I update my mac and ubuntu server last night. And something weird thing happen to the ".bash_profile" and other similar files.

### Change

#### Mac

On mac, I noticed two changes:

1.The file permission on those files have changed from 744 to 644 and thus I can't directly executed the them. And if I do change back 744 and execute them, I got error like:

```
$ -bash(3663,0x7fff79abd310) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb753d06160: pointer being     freed was not allocated
$ *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
$ Abort trap: 6
```

2.And when I use `bash` command with file(644)

```
$ bash .bash_profile
```

It will work partially, print any `echo` commands in the file, but the `alias` commands in the file won't work.

And only the source command with file(644)

```
$ source .bash_profile
```

works to both `echo` and `alias` command.

And as I guess where concerns some file permission problem in `alias`, I use:

```
$ sudo bash .bash_profile
```

It won't work, either.

And logging into will work both `echo` and `alias`.

#### Ubuntu

The second change happened to my ubuntu server, but not the first change.

## Question

1. Do anyone has any idea on that? Why echo works but alias don't?
2. I suppose this is a new update.And as I am new to the administrator field, I wonder where could I get this kind of notice of information.

Thx a lot!

Comment: The bash profile is not supposed to be *executed*, it's supposed to be *sourced* into the current shell. Therefore it does not require execute permissions. Weird error though.

Comment: @glennjackman I guess you are right. However, I used to do that and it worked. I don't know what is the differences now. Justing wondering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a bash script, that script runs within a new subshell which dies when the script exits. So your alias commands only affect that subshell, not the outer shell from which you executed the script. However, the subshell remains connected to the same terminal as the outer shell, which is why you can still see the output of your echo commands.

When you source a bash script, no subshell is spawned. Instead, the commands in the script are executed one by one as though you had typed them in. So the alias commands get called within the same shell from which you sourced your .bash_profile, and the aliases become available within that shell.

Comment: Thx, but I kinds of remember that "alias" worked before when using `./`. Is there any explanation for that?

Comment: Is it possible you're thinking of "." rather than "./"?  ("." is a synonym for "source")